# Как ввести ввести значение в String без переноса строки?

Tags: java, консоль, input

Раньше с такой проблемой не сталкивался. Я хочу ввести данные в формате:

```
fds dsa ase grf gfd ktf end
```

где end - "стоп-слово", и записать их в массив.
Я написал следующий код:

```
List<String> words = new ArrayList();
String word = "";
while (word != "end") {
    word = input.nextLine();
    words.add(word);
}
words.remove(words.size() - 1);
```

Но даже после ввода end программа просит меня вводить дальше. Как быть?

Comment: Нет, вы ошиблись, вопрос совершенно по другой теме

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте пожалуйста так

```
List<String> words = new ArrayList();
String word = "";
while (!word.equals("end")) {
    word = input.next();
    words.add(word);
}
words.remove(words.size() - 1);
```

Comment: Попробовал, по-прежнему бесконечно запрашивает ввод :(

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    List<String> words = new ArrayList<>()
    String word = "";
    while (!word.equals("end")) {
        word = input.nextLine();
        words.add(word);
    }
    words.remove(words.size() - 1);
    words.forEach(System.out::print);
}
```

И это однозначно: Возможный дубликат вопроса: Как сравнивать строки в Java?